How to interpret 'number of connectors' in Corsair PSU manual?
I have slight difficulty in understanding ‘Total Connectors’ number as mentioned in Corsair PSU manuals. More specifically the EPS connector.
Some of the newer power hungry boards & CPUs now need 8+4 EPS power connection.
I refer to Corsair RMx PSU manual. e.g. RM750x

It shows EPS (4+4) Connectors per cable 1 , total connectors 2.
Now does it mean it indeed as 4+4 as one cable & another 4+4 cable as well, together making it 8+8?
So that one can plug in 4+4 in 8 Pin socket and another 4 in remaining 4 Pin EPS socket. Making it 8+4 EPS connection.
A confirmation shall be great because it’s bit confusing to me.
Thanks.

Total Connectors = Qty x Connectors Per Cable
This is clear if you look at the Peripheral cable example. There are 4 connectors, but 2 cables are included so in total you have 8.
For EPS/ATX12V 8 pin (4+4) cables, 2 are included and each is 4+4. This will support 8+4 or 8+8 if you require.

